# Binding OBJECT ARRAY to OPTIONS VALUES of a SELECT in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a hash of objects, and the ID of this hash is binding to a RADIO BUTTON. When the user select this radio, I need to populate a select tag with options based on attribute of this model. 
Its hard to explain, so I created a Codepen to show what I want:
http://codepen.io/rizidoro/pen/BeJjf

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you yelling at me :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/adnan-i/pen/gLtap) binding dynamically to a single SELECT element, with a working ng-model binding on selection change:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="attr in data">
      <input type="radio" name='data-attr' value='{{attr.id}}' ng-model="selected.id" />{{attr.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <select ng-model="selected.value" ng-options="item.name for item in selectedAttr.values "></select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.selected = {};

  $scope.data =  [
    {"id":"113000",
      "name":"Size",
      "values":
          [{"id":"92029","name":"Size A"},
           {"id":"92030","name":"Size B"}]
    },
    {"id":"113002",
      "name":"Color",
      "values":
          [{"id":"94029","name":"Blue"},
           {"id":"94030","name":"Black"}]
    }
  ];

  $scope.$watch('selected.id', function(id){
    delete $scope.selected.value;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(attr){
      if(attr.id === id){
        $scope.selectedAttr = attr;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: $watch docs are under scope page: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Answer (score 2):

I have created a fiddle, that may solve ur problem. http://jsfiddle.net/qY2Zz/.

1. Seperated the data to a service.

   `animateAppModule.service('data', function(){...})`
2. Assigned a model to the select box.

   `ng-model="$scope.selectedOption"`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/wagedomain/afuz5/

I rewrote your HTML a little - not using ul / li tags where a div or span would suffice. Makes it easier.

Basically, inside the ng-repeat, you can do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="attr in data">
      <input type='radio' name='data-attr' value='{{attr.id}}' />{{attr.name}}   
      <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.name for item in attr.values "></select>
</div>
```

It's the ng-options that makes this work. I also added a $scope.selected variable to model bind to but I'm not doing anything with it in the fiddle. Use as you need.

Comment: Hi James, it's almost that... but I don't want a select for each type.  It will be only ONE select and will be populated based on the radio value... you got it?